# Stream Logitech C615 using mjpeg-streamer

Tags: usb, webcam, streaming

recently I thought about making a streaming camera with my Pi and a Logitech C615 I had, so I followed a tutorial on [MAKE.com](http://makezine.com/projects/raspberry-eye-remote-servo-cam/), but I haven't been able to get it streaming properly. I'm up to the point where I should begin streaming, but I always get the error:

```
ERROR opening V4L interface: No such file or directory
Init v4L2 failed !! exit fatal
i: init_VideoIn failed
```

when I run

```
./mjpg_streamer  -i "./input_uvc.so" -o "./output_http.so -w ./www" &
```

Any suggestions? Honestly, my Pi experience has been a total nightmare getting anything useful working, so I might just chunk mine.
Thanks!

Comment: Might be that you don't have sufficient privileges. Try running it with `sudo` e.g. `sudo ./mjpg_streamer  -i "./input_uvc.so" -o "./output_http.so -w ./www" &`

Comment: @Bex I'll give that a whirl.

Comment: @Bex, ok so, now I get a 404 error on the image.

Comment: On what image? What is the error?